# ASP.NET development server: possible misconfiguration?

Tags: c#, .net, routes, url-routing, aspnet-development-server

I'm facing a weird issue. I'm developing a website using C# and .NET 4, and I want to add routing service. After following several tutorials (unsuccessfully), I finally put myself in using an example and then build my website upon it. Once done that, I realized my weird problem: **routing's correct behavior depends on site's virtual path** (!).

In effect, running two websites with identical code (including configs) but under two different virtual paths (let's name 'em **mySite** and **myExample**), I found myExample correctly rewrite my urls, and mySite throw me a 404 error (just like routing wouldn't exist).

Can't avoid mention mySite is actually the name of the first website I created, thus I believe it to be misconfgured somewhere in the development server.

Supposing my intuition is good, **how can I access asp.net development server configuration?**

thanks